# Extracting max value from each column in a table

Tags: matlab, max, matlab-table

I have generated a table of data with time in one column with attempts 1-10 in the next series of columns. I want to be able to extract the max value in each attempt for further analysis.

I have tried for table `MGA`

```
max = max(MGA(:, []))
```

I get the following error -- "You cannot subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires both row and variable subscripts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: Never do `max = max();`, you'll overload `max`, and you won't be able to use it again.

And to answer the question, you can do as follows (notice that I've kept the values in the first columns):

```
MGA
MGA =    
     1     5     3     8     9
     2     4     7     3     3
     3     8     7     6     9
     4     8     2     7     3
     5     2     2     9    10
     6     5     5    10     4
     7     5    10     6     2
     8     7     4     2     3
     9     8     6     2     7
    10     8     3     3     5

max_values = [MGA(:,1), max(MGA(:,2:end),[],2)]
max_values =    
     1     9
     2     7
     3     9
     4     8
     5    10
     6    10
     7    10
     8     7
     9     8
    10     8
```

Comment: Assuming he actually has a [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) you will need to index `MGA` with curly brackets, and the concatenation isn't going to return a table.

Comment: You'll end up with something like `MGA.RowMax = max(MGA{:,2:end}, [], 2);`